# Installing Windows XP Embedded in ARM tablets

Tags: windows-xp-embedded

Is it possible to install windows xp embedded to ARM tablets? If so, how?
What are the ARM SoC that supports windows xp embedded?

Is it possible to install windows xp embedded to Intel Atom tablets? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible to run `Windows XP Embedded` on ARM hardware.  This is the entire reason `Windows RT` was released.

Comment: How about Intel Atom tablets?